# AWS Codebuild & Cloudfront: testing deployment after build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to e2e test a web app's staging environment built and deployed by CodeBuild & Cloudfront. The problem is that I can't test the latest changes until Cloudfront clears its cache across regions, which can take up to 15 mins.

I want to run this test during or after the Codebuild `post_build` phase, but unfortunately the static assets aren't updated in almost any region at that point.

Without this ability, I'll either have to settle with running the test manually and/or periodically. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the AWS CLI to do this.

I already had this command in my buildspec.yml file -

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation \
  --distribution-id ${CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID} \
  --paths /*
```

It worked after I followed the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html), and replaced `/*` with `"/*"`.

Now the cache invalidation is instant